# Is this a famous aviator / airplane?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

This may be a little off topic but I could not find a better community or website.

I have two photo postcards with a man in front of a plane. Pretty sure it's Charles Lindbergh but an exhaustive Google search for anything related visually has only turned up another picture of CL with a similar jacket on. So is this who I think it is? Can anyone come up with a "verifiable" narrative to accompany these photos? Perhaps the type of plane in the background?

[image: Photo1]

[image: Photo2]

Comment: I don't believe it is Charles Lindbergh, Lindbergh has a pretty noticeable divot in his chin, this gentleman does not.

Comment: Are you sure that is a plane?

Comment: @mins - I think you're getting closer, but the door isn't that wide. The subject of the photo definitely seems to be Chamberlin, and the stamp on the photos indicate they were taken in Boblingen, Germany. The upper part of the stamp is probably the name of the photographer, but I can't make it out... Rich Lummle, maybe?

Comment: I couldn't identify the plane, but using the stamps I found the specific date & location of the photos. The plane wasn't his, it was just one he was boarding at the time for a short flight.

Comment: @Omegacron: Publisher: Richi Lämmle, Böblingen [as here](http://www.swissair00.ch/fokker-f.viib-3m-.html).

Comment: BTW, if I were the OP I'd have these photos lovingly framed in glass on my wall. And now that we know the who, when & where, I'd have that info on a little bronze plaque on the frame. And I'd love them, and look at them for inspiration, and growl at my wife if she threatens to dust them off.

Comment: I think the plane is a Lufthansa [Dornier Merkur](http://www.wikiwand.com/de/Dornier_Merkur) airliner.

Comment: @TomMcW - I think you're right. Would you mind if I add that to my answer?

Comment: @Omegacron Sure

Comment: @TomMcW: Maybe the reason is in this article dated June 14: "Early tomorrow morning Chamberlin and Levine will motor to Karlsruhe and will proceed from there by airplane to Friedrichshafen, where they will inspect the Zeppelin and Dornier Merkur Works. They will next visit Stuttgart and Frankfort and will go to Hanover Thursday, and from Hanover to Bremen to meet their wives, who are due Friday from New York on the steamer Berlin." [Source](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/88487697/).

Comment: Good find @mins - now we just need to identify the tail number of that specific plane and we're there! Looks like D14-something (assuming there's a "1" behind him in the top photo), but haven't found a better picture of him boarding yet.

Comment: Luthansa had 30 Komets in service, so we know it was most likely one of those. And it looks like those all had a tail number starting with D-1-something.

Comment: Correction - the Komet III prototype in 1925 had a tail number of D-815, so that last comment may not be correct.

Comment: @Omegacron [This site](http://www.histaviation.com/Dornier_Merkur.html) seems to list all aircraft of the type made. Looks like there were several with D-1XXX.

Comment: Btw, I totally want a jacket like that!

Comment: @mins - awesome find, I'll go through that and see if I can narrow it down. Also still searching for a different angle that shows more of the number.

Comment: @Campbell - all joking aside, if those are original postcards and not recent reprints, you should seriously consider ordering a couple of those hard plastic snap-shut cases to protect them. Lots of places online like Amazon sell them, and they're generally pretty cheap. You just need to measure the postcards to get the size right. Stay away from the flimsy clear sleeves as much as possible - you want the rigid plastic ones that snap shut tightly.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm giving up on the tail number chase. At least seven of the tail numbers on that list operated out of the airfield at some point, and the number behind Chamberlin could be any of five of those, possibly six (if that's a "7"). Unless someone can find a better picture revealing more of the number, or an article listing the actual flight, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The pictures are of Clarence Chamberlin, after he landed near Boeblingen in 1927. Thanks to Omegacron for pointing out this website, which also has the exact same picture as the 2nd one you have. https://www.boeblingen.de/,Lde/start/WirtschaftEntwicklung/Chamberlin.html

Notice the similar bouquet of flowers, postcards in his front left jacket pocket, and how his jacket is buttoned.

[image]

[image]
([gettyimages](http://www.gettyimages.ae/detail/news-photo/transatlantic-competitor-clarence-chamberlin-being-carried-news-photo/2665562#transatlantic-competitor-clarence-chamberlin-being-carried-aloft-on-picture-id2665562))

Comment: @ymb1, will do that thanks, thought it went without saying. I couldn't find markings on the New York which match the 1st picture (looks like a capital D), so am kind of stumped on that so far.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for the find, but that quote is wrong. He was flying the "Miss Columbia" when he landed in Eisleben. He CAME from New York, so maybe that's where the confusion was.

Comment: @Omegacron, corrected and sourced, thanks! I would add the matching picture to your post!

Answer (score 25):

Thanks to the research of the other two answers, I finally found the context for these two photos. They are indeed of [Clarence Chamberlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarence_Chamberlin) (a contemporary of Lindbergh) and were taken on June 15, 1927 at the Stuttgart-Boeblingen Airfield in Germany. The following page describes the events leading up to the photos, although the original is in German:

https://www.boeblingen.de/,Lde/start/WirtschaftEntwicklung/Chamberlin.html

Long story short, he was attempting to beat Charles Lindbergh on the transatlantic record, but Lindbergh won due to numerous delays. Chamberlin decided to go a little further, to Berlin, and beat the distance record instead. There were numerous technical problems with his plane, however (the *Miss Columbia*), and he ended up having to land in Eisleben, about 90 miles west of his goal on June 6, 1927. After a day spent repairing the plane, he then proceeded to Berlin. The event seen in the photos is a parade/celebration thrown in his honor as he leaves on the 15th.

By comparison, here's a photo from the same event showing Chamberlin in the same clothes:

[image]

I was unable to identify the specific plane behind him in the photos, but it was NOT the *Miss Columbia*. Due to the many technical problems experienced during the race, Chamberlin elected to return by sea. What we see in the photos is him about to board a passenger plane that will take him to the ship. As far as I can tell, the *Miss Columbia* was shipped back separately, although his co-pilot (and the plane's owner) [Charles Levine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_A._Levine) wanted to fly it back despite the problems.

---

**What About the Plane Type?**

The plane that Chamberlin is boarding in the photos looks to be a [Dornier Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Komet), which was a common passenger plane in Germany at the time. The door size/shape and top of the plane (what we can see, at least) match up quite nicely. Here's a shot of one from a similar angle:

[image]

*Thanks to @TomMcW for finding that.*

Comment: You are correct, the 2nd picture is there exactly as well

Comment: There's a lot about Lindberg, Chamberlin and Levine in one of Bill Bryson's newer books, Summer 1927, really interesting read. Aviation features heavily. https://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/sep/26/one-summer-1927-bill-bryson-review

Answer (score 18):

[image]
([wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Clarence_Duncan_Chamberlin_and_Thea_Rasche_1927.jpg))

I may be wrong, but it looks very like [Clarence Chamberlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarence_Chamberlin); the Wikipedia picture is quite small, but if you look at [some other pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=Clarence%20Chamberlin&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTl8_ytNvSAhXFuBQKHZssDHwQ_AUICSgC&biw=1440&bih=794) you can see a very strong resemblance. According to Wikipedia he carried the first transatlantic passenger, flew an aircraft off a ship, and was a famous barnstormer. So there are plenty of reasons why he could have ended up on postcards.

I don't know what the aircraft is. Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarence_Chamberlin#.22Miss_Columbia.22) that Chamberlin's most well-known aircraft was *Miss Columbia*, a [Wright-Bellanca WB-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright-Bellanca_WB-2). But the pictures of it show it has a square door under the wing, whereas your pictures show a rounded door rear of the wing. He was also associated with the "Curtiss Condor CO" (a [Curtiss T-32 Condor II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_T-32_Condor_II)?) but again, it doesn't seem to match visually.

Comment: Another [picture with the same jacket](http://www.lesliejonesphotography.com/collection/0806001542), and another [postcard](http://www.ak-ansichtskarten.de/ak/90-carte-postale-ancienne/25988-Aviation-Civile-avant-1945/6335940-AK-Atlantikflieger-Clarence-Chamberlin-mit-Blumenstrauss/?&lang=6).

Comment: @ymb1: Well it's Pondlife 's answer, he decides (he's in charge, he's the boss, the head man, the top dog, the big cheese, the head honcho, number one)

Comment: @mins you forgot "el numero uno"