# Who is this flyer seen in Oakland c. 1929?

Tags: aviation-history

Looking for identification of the man on the left. Second from left is W.A. "Sandy" Sanders, third is Denny Wright, and fourth is Clyde Sunderland.

[image]
Oakland, around 1929.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36336 ? :D

Comment: Are we supposed to know who "Sandy" Sanders, Denny Wright, and Clyde Sunderland are? A google search (for your last question) revealed that Clyde is a photographer, but I don't know who the other ones are (nor does a search help) and how they are related to aviation history?

Comment: Thank you for your question, it is well taken: I am fishing here, and I hope I am not abusing the forum.  Wright and Sanders owned and ran "the oldest aviation school at Oakland Airport".  (photo to follow).  Clyde Sunderland is the real bait here. He was not just 'a photographer' ( https://gregyoungpublishing.com/clyde-sunderland/), he is considered to be on a par with Ansel Adams. There are few pictures of he, himself, however.  So, yeah, I was hoping for some bites.  Early aviation history is turning out to be much more localized than I expected.

Comment: I have very much found this question off topic as at Aviation SE we are here to ask questions, not to identify people

Comment: @super, there is a photo showing two pilots managing an aviation school and another one being a lead character in aerial photography. The two businesses where conducted at Oakland airport. The fourth person could be a pilot too. Identifying pilots is not that different from identifying aircraft or aviation places.